# Azure Form Recognizer Resource Usage Metrics

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-cognitive-services

I was wondering if there is a place where I can find the following metrics for Form Recognizer API

- Number of API calls per time frame
- Number of "pages" processed in each call

I can see the cost analysis stuff, but I want to know those specific metric values.

Thanks in advance!
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks they are not the supported metrics of the resource `Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts`, all the supported metrics and their metric values are list here.

Reference - [Supported metrics with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported#microsoftcognitiveservicesaccounts)